# Create a Git server on Local Network without using third party software or applications

Tags: git, networking, local

I'm trying to create a local server in our network to allow the team to use Git to maintain our code. My boss doesn't want to use third party services like GitHub and such, so I'm trying to find a way to set up a server we could use to maintain our code. We're all running Windows 8 and have Git 1.8.4 and are all connected to the local router in our office.

I've tried using SSH but can't get it to work, I've tried putting the Git Repo in the computer we shall use as a server and have everyone connect to it but it has also failed. I tried Git-Daemon also but I can't get it to work either.

Is there any possible way to create a local network server and implement Git in it?

Comment: If your team is not too big and you don't want to throw to much bucks at this you could give atlassian stash a try.

Comment: I'll suggest install a Linux server for Git (even a VM, for example, you'll have a gitorious appliance [here](http://getgitorious.com/install-gitorious) )

Comment: What about SSH didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

**Check out [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/)** - Its a lot like Github except its open source, free and you can of course download it and host it on your own private infrastructure.